# AngularJS and Django: Conflicting routing

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, angular-ui-router

So, I was integrating AngularJS with a Django backend.

For loading the HTML partials/templates I am using angularjs' **ui-router**. Here's my angularjs code:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("home", {
        url: "",
        controller: "HomeCtrl as home",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/home.html"
    })
    .state("feed", {
        url: "/feed",
        controller: "FeedCtrl as feed",
        templateUrl: "/static/templates/feed.html"
    })
}
```

My **home state loads fine**. But when I try to load the feed state, I get the following error:

[image]

I am guessing Django is interfering with angularjs' routing? How do I handle this?

Comment: How are you trying to load feed state? By entering URL directly or clicking some link when home state is loaded?

Comment: entering url directly? Should this matter?

Comment: Ok got it! should have entered 'baseurl/#/feed' instead of 'baseurl/feed'. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you're entering directly that URL, AngularJS can't catch it because it is not loaded. If you want to have URLs without #, you should return same angular template from django when entering any URL managed by angularjs directly

Answer (score 1):

Django have to handle "feed" state same way as "home" state.

```
url(r'^(feed)?$', "your_app.views.home")
```

The best way is probably handle all remaining urls by home view and deal with it in angular later. Add this at the last line of your urls.py

```
url(r'^.*$', "your_app.views.home", name='home'),
```

And do not forgot activete HTML5 mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```